# How do you connect a tcp client from one virtual machine(linux on desktop) to a tcp server on a different virtual machine(linux on laptop)?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am getting my feet wet in sockets programming. So here is the main problem: I have a physical desktop with an installed virtual machine running ubuntu. I am using the vim editor to write a server in the C language.

What I can do just fine is open two terminals on my physical desktop's virtual machine (one as a client and one as a server) and set the client to reach out to the local host 127.0.0.1. I am able to do this just fine.

What I cannot seem to do is start my server on my physical desktop's virtual machine and then run a client on a physical laptop's virtual machine (ubuntu just the same.)

I will post the code below:

### TCP_CLIENT.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct _test_struct{
    
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
} test_struct_t;


typedef struct result_struct_{

    unsigned int c;

} result_struct_t;

#define DEST_PORT            2000
#define SERVER_IP_ADDRESS   "127.0.0.1"

test_struct_t client_data;
result_struct_t result;

void
setup_tcp_communication(){

    /*Step 1 : Initialization*/
    /*Socket handle*/
    int sockfd = 0, 
        sent_recv_bytes = 0;

    int addr_len = 0;

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    /*to store socket addesses : ip address and port*/
    struct sockaddr_in dest;

    /*Step 2: specify server information*/
    /*Ipv4 sockets, Other values are IPv6*/
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /*Client wants to send data to server process which is running on server machine, and listening on 
     * port on DEST_PORT, server IP address SERVER_IP_ADDRESS.
     * Inform client about which server to send data to : All we need is port number, and server ip address. Pls note that
     * there can be many processes running on the server listening on different no of ports, 
     * our client is interested in sending data to server process which is lisetning on PORT = DEST_PORT*/ 
    dest.sin_port = DEST_PORT;
    struct hostent *host = (struct hostent *)gethostbyname(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS);
    dest.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);

    /*Step 3 : Create a TCP socket*/
    /*Create a socket finally. socket() is a system call, which asks for three paramemeters*/
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);


    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest,sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    /*Step 4 : get the data to be sent to server*/
    /*Our client is now ready to send data to server. sendto() sends data to Server*/

PROMPT_USER:

    /*prompt the user to enter data*/
    printf("Enter a : ?\n");
    scanf("%u", &client_data.a);
    printf("Enter b : ?\n");
    scanf("%u", &client_data.b);

    
    /*step 5 : send the data to server*/
    sent_recv_bytes = sendto(sockfd, 
           &client_data,
           sizeof(test_struct_t), 
           0, 
           (struct sockaddr *)&dest, 
           sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    
    printf("No of bytes sent = %d\n", sent_recv_bytes);
   
    /*Step 6 : Client also want to reply from server after sending data*/
    
    /*recvfrom is a blocking system call, meaning the client program will not run past this point
     * untill the data arrives on the socket from server*/
    sent_recv_bytes =  recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)&result, sizeof(result_struct_t), 0,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &addr_len);

    printf("No of bytes recvd = %d\n", sent_recv_bytes);
    
    printf("Result recvd = %u\n", result.c);
    /*Step 7: Client would want to send the data again to the server, go into infinite loop*/
    goto PROMPT_USER;
}
    

int
main(int argc, char **argv){

    setup_tcp_communication();
    printf("application quits\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### TCP_SERVER.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
/*Server process is running on this port no. Client has to send data to this port no*/
#define SERVER_PORT     2000 

typedef struct _test_struct{
        
        unsigned int a;
        unsigned int b;
    } test_struct_t;
    
    
    typedef struct result_struct_{
    
        unsigned int c;
    
    } result_struct_t;

test_struct_t test_struct;
result_struct_t res_struct;
char data_buffer[1024];

void
setup_tcp_server_communication(){

    /*Step 1 : Initialization*/
    /*Socket handle and other variables*/
    /*Master socket file descriptor, used to accept new client connection only, no data exchange*/
    int master_sock_tcp_fd = 0, 
        sent_recv_bytes = 0, 
        addr_len = 0, 
        opt = 1;

    /*client specific communication socket file descriptor, 
     * used for only data exchange/communication between client and server*/
    int comm_socket_fd = 0;     
    /* Set of file descriptor on which select() polls. Select() unblocks whever data arrives on 
     * any fd present in this set*/
    fd_set readfds;             
    /*variables to hold server information*/
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, /*structure to store the server and client info*/
                       client_addr;

    /*step 2: tcp master socket creation*/
    if ((master_sock_tcp_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP )) == -1)
    {
        printf("socket creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Step 3: specify server Information*/
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;/*This socket will process only ipv4 network packets*/
    server_addr.sin_port = SERVER_PORT;/*Server will process any data arriving on port no 2000*/
    
    /*3232249957; //( = 192.168.56.101); Server's IP address, 
    //means, Linux will send all data whose destination address = address of any local interface 
    //of this machine, in this case it is 192.168.56.101*/
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    /* Bind the server. Binding means, we are telling kernel(OS) that any data 
     * you recieve with dest ip address = 192.168.56.101, and tcp port no = 2000, pls send that data to this process
     * bind() is a mechnism to tell OS what kind of data server process is interested in to recieve. Remember, server machine
     * can run multiple server processes to process different data and service different clients. Note that, bind() is 
     * used on server side, not on client side*/

    if (bind(master_sock_tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("socket bind failed\n");
        return;
    }

    /*Step 4 : Tell the Linux OS to maintain the queue of max length to Queue incoming
     * client connections.*/
    if (listen(master_sock_tcp_fd, 5)<0)  
    {
        printf("listen failed\n");
        return;
    }

    /* Server infinite loop for servicing the client*/

    while(1){

        /*Step 5 : initialze and dill readfds*/
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);                     /* Initialize the file descriptor set*/
        FD_SET(master_sock_tcp_fd, &readfds);  /*Add the socket to this set on which our server is running*/

        printf("blocked on select System call...\n");


        /*Step 6 : Wait for client connection*/
        /*state Machine state 1 */
        
        /*Call the select system call, server process blocks here. Linux OS keeps this process blocked untill the data arrives on any of the file Drscriptors in the 'readfds' set*/
        select(master_sock_tcp_fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

        /*Some data on some fd present in set has arrived, Now check on which File descriptor the data arrives, and process accordingly*/
        if (FD_ISSET(master_sock_tcp_fd, &readfds))
        { 
            /*Data arrives on Master socket only when new client connects with the server (that is, 'connect' call is invoked on client side)*/
            printf("New connection recieved recvd, accept the connection. Client and Server completes TCP-3 way handshake at this point\n");

            /* step 7 : accept() returns a new temporary file desriptor(fd). Server uses this 'comm_socket_fd' fd for the rest of the
             * life of connection with this client to send and recieve msg. Master socket is used only for accepting
             * new client's connection and not for data exchange with the client*/
            /* state Machine state 2*/
            comm_socket_fd = accept(master_sock_tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
            if(comm_socket_fd < 0){

                /* if accept failed to return a socket descriptor, display error and exit */
                printf("accept error : errno = %d\n", errno);
                exit(0);
            }

            printf("Connection accepted from client : %s:%u\n", 
                inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

            while(1){
                printf("Server ready to service client msgs.\n");
                /*Drain to store client info (ip and port) when data arrives from client, sometimes, server would want to find the identity of the client sending msgs*/
                memset(data_buffer, 0, sizeof(data_buffer));

                /*Step 8: Server recieving the data from client. Client IP and PORT no will be stored in client_addr
                 * by the kernel. Server will use this client_addr info to reply back to client*/

                /*Like in client case, this is also a blocking system call, meaning, server process halts here untill
                 * data arrives on this comm_socket_fd from client whose connection request has been accepted via accept()*/
                /* state Machine state 3*/
                sent_recv_bytes = recvfrom(comm_socket_fd, (char *)data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 0,
                        (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

                /* state Machine state 4*/
                printf("Server recvd %d bytes from client %s:%u\n", sent_recv_bytes, 
                        inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

                if(sent_recv_bytes == 0){
                /*If server recvs empty msg from client, server may close the connection and wait
                 * for fresh new connection from client - same or different*/
                close(comm_socket_fd);
                break; /*goto step 5*/

                }

                test_struct_t *client_data = (test_struct_t *)data_buffer;
                
                /* If the client sends a special msg to server, then server close the client connection
                 * for forever*/
                /*Step 9 */
                if(client_data->a == 0 && client_data->b ==0){

                    close(comm_socket_fd);
                    printf("Server closes connection with client : %s:%u\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
                    /*Goto state machine State 1*/
                    break;/*Get out of inner while loop, server is done with this client, time to check for new connection request by executing selct()*/
                }

                result_struct_t result;
                result.c = client_data->a + client_data->b;

                /* Server replying back to client now*/
                sent_recv_bytes = sendto(comm_socket_fd, (char *)&result, sizeof(result_struct_t), 0,
                        (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

                printf("Server sent %d bytes in reply to client\n", sent_recv_bytes);
                /*Goto state machine State 3*/
            }
        }
    }/*step 10 : wait for new client request again*/    
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv){

    setup_tcp_server_communication();
    return 0;
}
```

**What I tried:**

1. I tried replacing the ip address in tcp_client.c with VMware VMnet1 and VMware VMnet 8's respective ip addresses.

result: The client runs but the server does not read the connection. The client allows me to input two numbers and then the client shuts down.

2. I tried getting the server's ip address from the virtual machine typing: aip addr in ubuntu's terminal.

result: the exact same result. The client allows me to type number a and b, but the server doesnt register the connection from the client.

3. I tried my physical desktop's actual ip address.

result: The tcp client does not allow me to do any inputs but only stays idle.

My guess which I havent tried yet is that I have to create an apache server for my desktop. Which I know nothing about. I have no further clue what is going wrong and would like some insight from the more experienced. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server should be at its respective VM IP address, port 2000.  Try `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` before running the server to verify the port is not in use. Then start the server and look again. It should be there. Whether the client can connect to it from another VM is about VM settings.  Check VMWare docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did some digging and I found something about port forwarding. Does that sound like its on the right path?

Comment: There should be a lot of tutorials on the matter, but yes, you need to set up your VMs to use a common network for different VMs on the same host, or to do port forwarding for the server's VMs on different hosts. -- Anyway, before tackling issues with your software _and_ the networking, use netcat as server and clients. These are know to be working programs. This removes at least one potential source of errors.